# Is there a way to make space input obligatory in the scanf() function?

Tags: c, input, scanf, whitespace

For example, I want to make a user type a required message before values, like this:

```
scanf(" Message%c", &character);
```

That's fine, but then I want this message to contain some spaces like this:

```
scanf(" A required message %c", &character);
```

The compiler does not complain about anything, but the spaces do not matter, the input:

```
A required message C
```

and

```
ArequiredmessageC
```

give the same result.

Is there a way to make these spaces mandatory?

Comment: Use `fgets()` for user input.

Comment: One big advantage of using `fgets` is that if input doesn't match at any point, you can discard the buffer and input another; but using `scanf` the unprocessed text remains in the input buffer.

Comment: @pmg I know there are some other input functions, but I only asked about this one

Comment: `scanf` gets its name from "scan formatted" ... user input is as unformatted as it gets.. Using scanf for user input may be easy and fast for simple toy snippets. When you start adding rules and limitations and impositions, do yourself a favor and switch to `fgets()`

Comment: @Blayer Bond the required prefix is only for %c, it does not matter as well, the result will be the same if I type in like " Arequiredmessage" or "Arequiredmessage" or " A required message" or whatever. The point is that it simply skips the spaces

Comment: That is because a whitespace character in the format string causes `scanf` to skip *any number* (including none) of whitespace characters in the input.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, in my code this scanf follows another one, so if I do not specify the prefix space, it skips the whole input when I press Enter for the previous scanf function

Comment: Kaiyaha recommend 1) Not use `fgets(stdin)` and `scanf()` in the same code. 2) Don't use `scanf()`,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `%[` conversion specifier with a `1` length modifier and a `*` to suppress assignment:

```
if (scanf("%*1[ ]A%*1[ ]required%*1[ ]message%*1[ ]%c", &character) == 1) {
    // Input is conforming, last character is in `character`
} else {
    // Input is not as expected...
    // but there is no way to tell how many characters were correct
}
```

This is very cumbersome and hard to read. You could use `fgets()` as an alternative:

```
char buf[80];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) {
    const char *prefix = " A required message ";
    size_t len = strlen(prefix);
    if (!memcmp(buf, prefix, len)) {
        char c = buf[len];
        // handle correct message
    } else {
        printf("Invalid input: %s", buf);
    }
} else {
    printf("Unexpected end of file\n");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can explicitly match one space:

```
scanf("%*1[ ]A%*1[ ]required%*1[ ]message%*1[ ]%c", &character);
```